# node js restler result "get" not complete when trying to return result

Tags: node.js, restler

I'm trying to get the HTML of a website using restler. But when I try to get the relevant part of result, I always get the error,

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'rawEncoded' of undefined".

'rawEncoded' sometimes is 'res'. I think it changes based on processing time.

I'm trying to get result.request.res.rawEncode from restler get result.

My function:

```
var rest = require('restler');

var loadHtmlUrl = function(weburl) {
    var resultstr = rest.get(weburl).on('complete', function(result) {
        var string = result.request.res.rawEncode;
        return string;
    });
    return resultstr;
};
```

Then:

```
var htmlstring = loadHtmlUrl('http://google.com');
```

Maybe restler is the entirely wrong way to go. Maybe I don't understand it completely. But I'm definitely stuck...

Thanks!

Comment: You have a number of mistakes in your code, check it up (e.g. equals sign after `var` in the second piece of code)

Comment: sorry, fixed that up. was rushed writing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Would your `return resultstr;` not run before the `on('complete'` callback gets called because it is asynchronous, therefore resulting in your `htmlstring` being null? I think you need to have a callback as a parameter to your `loadHtmlUrl` like so:

```
var rest = require('restler');

var loadHtmlUrl = function(weburl, callback) {
    var resultstr = rest.get(weburl).on('complete', function(result) {
      callback(result.request.res.rawEncode);
    });
};
```

And then call it like so:

```
var htmlstring = null;
loadHtmlUrl('http://google.com', function(rawEncode) {
  htmlstring = rawEncode;
  //Do your stuff here...
});
```

I think that will resolve future problems you will have. However, I think the real problem you're facing is that result.request does not have the property of `res`. I'm thinking that my change above may fix this problem (not quite sure how). If not, then I would recommend looking at what properties `result.request` has as a debugging starter...