# Getting HTTP Response using restler in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpresponse, restler

I don't understand why this code doesn't work for me

```
var rest = require('restler');

var getResp = function(url){
        var resp ="";
        rest.get(url).on('complete',function(response){
          resp = response.toString();
        });
        return resp;
    };
```

I am not getting the response for `getResp('google.com')`

Am I missing something with restler?

Comment: did you try `getResp('http://google.com')`?

Comment: something thing.. I get `''`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being that you're returning `resp` it looks like you've forgotten that the request is asynchronous. Instead try out this:

```
var rest = require('restler');

var getResp = function(url){
  rest.get(url).on('complete', function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
};

getResp('http://google.com/');

// output:
// <!doctype html><html itemscope="itemscope" ....
```

Because of its asynchronous nature it's preferred that you pass the value to a receiving callback. Take this small example:

```
var rest = require('restler');

// process an array of URLs
['http://google.com/',
'http://facebook.com/'].forEach(function(item) {
  getResp(item);
});

function getResp(url){
  rest.get(url).on('complete', function(response){
    processResponse(response);
  });
};

// data will be a Buffer
function processResponse(data) {
  // converting Buffers to strings is expensive, so I prefer
  // to do it explicitely when required
  var str = data.toString();
}
```

Once the data comes in you'll be able to pass it around like any other variable.

Comment: how to do I get that in a variable afterwards?

Comment: @NickGinanto I've added an example of how to pass the response around.

Answer (score 1):

`return resp;` is running before the `on('complete'` callback gets called because it is asynchronous. This is resulting is the `resp` variable never getting assigned a value.

Try this:

```
var rest = require('restler');

var getResp = function(url){
  var result = rest.get(url).on('complete', function(response){
   response;
  });
  return result;
};

getResp('http://google.com/');
```

You could also use a callback like in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17560819/1298944).

Comment: don't you mean `return result`?